# HAProxy frontend managing both layer 4 and layer 7

Tags: ssl-certificate, reverse-proxy, http, haproxy, tcp

I am using HAProxy as a reverse-proxy to route all my domain names into various servers in a private computer cluster. Most of the times, the traffic represents web apps or APIs and it makes sense to use HTTPS to serve them. So I've create a frontend in that fashion for this:

**frontend layer7-http-listener**

```
bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/httpd/certs/haproxy.pem
mode http
[...]
```

I also have one server that's expecting to receive TLS encrypted traffic and has its own certs. That means I have to revert to TCP to let data pass through without being decrypted in HAProxy. Also, HAProxy doesn't have to manage any certs in that situation. Something more like this:

**frontend layer4-listener**

```
bind *:443 ssl
mode tcp
[...]
```

As a noob, what I understand is that HAProxy can't have 2 fontends with similar binds, namely *:443 here.

What's the best way to handle this knowing that both situations come from different domain names. Ex: *httpapp.mydomain.com* for layer 7 and *tcpserver.mydomain.com* for layer 4

Answer (score 0):

I've never done it myself but you could use SNI to split the traffic?
An example is [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/628149/haproxy-route-https-sni-and-http-over-the-same-port):